# AWS API to get the price displayed on amazon site

Tags: amazon-web-services

On an Amazon site, there is usually a **List Price** and a **Price**. I am trying to figure out how to obtain **Price** programmatically.

For example: [This product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GDF48O) has **List Price** $35 and **Price** $26

Through the ItemLookUp API, the **List Price** can be obtained easily but is there a way to get the **Price** from Amazon API?

First I thought that 'price' is the price that amazon sells the item at, but for this previously mentioned [product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000GDF48O) this **Price** is $26 while the amazon's own lowest price is $28.76

Then I thought **Price** is the lowest price that is eligible for Prime, but I can't find easy way of getting this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make sure to include the [Offers response group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Offers.html), you can get the lowest new price, lowest used price, etc. And if you need to, you can filter it to only offers from Amazon. That should give you the functionality you're needing. You can also find out if a specific offer is eligible for super saver shipping through that response group - which should be the same ones that are prime eligible.

Here's some [more info on response groups and the different ones available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_ResponseGroupsList.html) - a very useful resource to dig through if you're wondering where to get a specific piece of info from.

I realize it's been a month since you asked this question, but I hope this helps. Let me know if you need any more clarification.